# Android mailing problem

Tags: android

I have a little but annoying problem. I have made an app where the user can give some directions and then send them by email later.

The problem is that when the user send the directions it do not change line if the user have pressed enter in the app. I am storing the directions as a `String` in the database on the phone.

It is showed correctly in the app.

Anyone knows what can be done?

**EDIT**

I am sending the mail by

```
intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/html");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml(body));
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share Via:"));
```

Thank you

Comment: how are you sending the email? Does the phone bring up a list of email clients on the phone for the user to launch?

Comment: @Rajath updated the question to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace carriage returns with `<br />` tags, eg:

```
html = Html.fromHtml(body.replace("\n", "<br/>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to print `Html.fromHtml(body)` to your log and see if the `ENTER` is seen?